# how to change $scope variable value and test angularjs jasmine

Tags: angularjs, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have the First case when product id should be undefined.

```
var $stateParamsStub = {
    scheduleId : undefined
}
```

In my controller, I am checking for isUpdate true or false. If productId is undefined it means isUpdate should be false in another case it should be true

```
$scope.isUpdate = stateParams.scheduleId ? true : false;
```

My Test File

```
$injector.invoke(myController, this, {
    $scope: $scope,
    $stateParams: $stateParamsStub    
});
```

My first test case, which is working as expected because I set  stateParams.scheduleId to undefined while injecting

```
it('should check update as false', function () {
    expect($scope.isUpdate).toBeFalsy();
});
```

My case 2, which is failing

```
it('should check update as false', function () {
    $stateParamsStub = {
        productId: "86C07C05-41FB-41E9"
    }
    $scope.$digest();
    expect($scope.isUpdate).toBeTruthy();
});
```

The output of the second case: `Expected false to be truthy.`

I know before every "**it**" before each gets executed where It is setting the default value which I assigned earlier. How to change that value for another test ? so it takes an updated value?

Comment: You're checking for `scheduleId`, but you've `productId` in the object. That's strange! Is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are counting on references, therefore, you must save the same ref.

try something like that:

```
it('should check update as false', function () {
    $stateParamsStub.scheduleId = "86C07C05-41FB-41E9"; // <-- the change

    $scope.$digest();
    expect($scope.isUpdate).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller code, I can see that you are comparing with scheduleId:

```
$scope.isUpdate = stateParams.scheduleId ? true : false;
```

But in your test case you are setting productId in your JSON. Align your test case and controller for a single attribute in JSON

Comment: sorry that was my mistake while posting question here, fixed in question.

Answer (score 0):

Since state params can be passed through only injecting which executed in beforeEach section, Hence we can not modify that.
So, I have updated directly controller scope value

```
it('should check update as true', function () {
$scope.isUpdate=true // <-- the change
$scope.$digest();
expect($scope.isUpdate).toBeTruthy();

<-- did some other testing based on this condition -->
}
```

Thank you all whoever has taken time to read my problem and provided possible ans.
});